# Pull Dismiss ViewController Without BackBarButton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

One of the best features I like in iOS 7 is the pull the dismiss option of ViewController. You can pull from the left side of the screen to return to the RootViewController.

But you cannot do this if you hide you hide your BackBarButton and put another button for dismissing. Is there a way to do so? Or do I need to use a open source control for that which I really don't want because it will ruin the uniformity of the application.

Comment: You could add a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to listen to the swipe motion and then return to the `RootViewController` ?

Comment: Do you know anywhere that I can find an exemplary code for this?